# Is there a graph of Namecoin value over time?

Tags: namecoin, charts

Where can I find a chart (or even raw data) of [Namecoin](http://dot-bit.org/) prices over time?
[NMC Watch](http://www.nmcwatch.com/index.php?p=charts) doesn't seem to provide a link to historical data, just one day.

In BTC? In USD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMC has it, why look elsewhere? https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/namecoin/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to see [historical Namecoin's price chart](http://www.nmcwatch.com/index.php?c=bpx&tf=1d) on NMC Watch, the link provides price chart from June 2 to current date.

Comment: The question itself states that the 24 hour historical price chart from NMC Watch is not an adequate data source. While I'm sure NMC Watch and the like *have* historical price data, they don't seem to make it available to the public. I believe they scrape their data from the [Bitparking NMC Exchange's History page](https://exchange.bitparking.com/uhistory) though so perhaps someone could start collecting a publicly accessible data source?

Comment: @David Perry, the link provides price chart from June 2 to current date

Comment: Somehow I missed that link ... where did you find it? NMC/BTC seems remarkably stable over the last 3-4 months.

Comment: My apologies, I did not notice that. I see now that the links on NMC Watch are setting the timeframe-per-data-point instead of the timeframe to watch. Still, the accompanying data would be nice :D

Answer (score 1):

also: http://nx.bit ( http://blockchained.com/namecoin )
including a curve of the number of names

Answer (score 1):

Most links above are dead... I'm looking for historical pricing of Namecoin in 2012 and 2013. Seems like most sources start in April 2013 while the coin was introduced in 2012 (correct me if I'm wrong).